# jquery creating double validation errors

Tags: javascript, jquery

The issue is duplicate error. For example click 'yes' for the first radio button and then select red only for the first drop down click submit and you will get 2 validations errors in quick succession. How do I remove the second?

Comment: what should you really get as the result here? I see you have written a code to display two alert messages?

Comment: @Jayanga select yes for first and hit submit. see 2 error messages?

Comment: @lukey Don't worry. Your question is clear. You don't want to have both error messages once right. I solved it. Answer is below.

Comment: @LasanthaBandara This works however it submits once i click ok on error?

Answer (score 0):

Change your click function like this.

```
$("input:submit").click(function() {

    var retVal = validate(1);


    if (!$("input[name=attendance1]").is(":checked")) {
        alert('Please select preference for 1');
        return false;
    }
    if (!$("input[name=attendance2]").is(":checked") && retVal) {
        alert('Please select preference for 2');
        return false;
    }
    if (!$("input[name=attendance3]").is(":checked") && retVal) {
        alert('Please select preference for 3');
        return false;
    }
});
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, generally callback functions are executed before form values are posted to the back end. After you click the ok button, it submits.

Comment: When live it does NOT alert me if attendance1, attendance2 or attendance3 are NOT checked then it submits. If I select 'yes' then do not choose colour and shade it will alert me that I have not selected the drop downs but then submits when i click ok